# CERT_HAS_EXPIRED - in post request to php from node js

Tags: node.js, http-post

I am trying to send data to a php script which will then be saved in the database. but i am getting an error saying `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` and today is my first time using node.js this is my node.js code

```
const https = require("https");
const qs = require("querystring");

var postData = qs.stringify({
  name: "Bright Isaac",
  age: "21",
});

var options = {
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 443,
  path: "/quelib/src/chats/post.php",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length": postData.length,
  },
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log("statusCode:", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers:", res.headers);

  res.on("data", (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on("error", (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

**Error**

```
$ node index.js
Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12) {
  code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED'
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "qmyapp.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "chat",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Bright Isaac",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**package-lock.json**

```
{
  "name": "qmyapp.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1
}
```

Please how do i properly fix this and also can anybody tell me if this is the proper way of sending a post request from node js to php. Thanks

P/S: if you need more explanation please ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fast way but INSECURE

Only use for debugging purposes!

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'`

## Best way to fix

Renew the certificate of php site using

https://github.com/skoerfgen/ACMECert